# Google analytics custom metrics not working for angular 6

Tags: angular, google-analytics, angular6, angular-components

I have created a custom metric on Google Analytics and mentioned the required variable in the template:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
declare let ga: Function;
@Injectable()
export class GoogleAnalyticsEventsService {

  public emitEvent(eventCategory: string,
                   eventAction: string,
                   eventLabel: string = null,
                   eventValue: number = null) {
    ga('send', 'event', {
      eventCategory: eventCategory,
      eventLabel: eventLabel,
      eventAction: eventAction,
      eventValue: eventValue
    });
  }

}
```

In my component I have mentioned it like this:

```
var metricValue = '1';
ga('set', 'metric6', metricValue);
```

But somehow, it's not working.  Kindly help

Comment: This is not enough information.  You'll need to show the template, probably the controller too, and may as well show where you include the analytics script as well.

Comment: @sh0ber thank you for the update, I have added the service code, please check and advice.

Comment: 1. Can you confirm you're using analytics.js as your form of GA implementation? 2. Can you see/show us the activity of your "network" tab in developer tools when you try to trigger an event?

Comment: 1. Yes we are using analytics.js in our GA implementation

Comment: I have attached the snap shot of network tab.

Comment: Can you tell me what isn't working? Also can you trigger an event and show the response from the "collect?" call in the "network" tab?